# Proguard returned error with Google Play Services library

Tags: android, google-play-services, proguard

I added Google Play Services library to my application. Everything works fine but size of my apk increase in 4 (!) times from 350KB to 1.6MB. For remove unused classes from Google Play Services library I decide to use ProGuard. But now I can not run project or export it to apk because ProGuard returned error. When I do not use GPS lib I have no problems with export but I can not create apk with this library.
I read a lot about this problem but any solution that I found did not help me.

Here is my proguard-project.txt (as recomended [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Proguard))

```
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

Here is my proguard.cng

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

#keep all classes that might be used in XML layouts
-keep public class * extends android.view.View
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.Fragment


#keep all public and protected methods that could be used by java reflection
-keepclassmembernames class * {
  public protected <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
  native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}


-keepclassmembers enum * {
  public static **[] values();
  public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-dontwarn **CompatHoneycomb
-dontwarn org.htmlcleaner.*
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil {*;}
-keep class com.google.ads.** { *;}
```

and here an error that I obtained after export to apk:

```
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary] Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]   Class       = [com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil]
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]   Method      = [showErrorDialogFragment(ILandroid/app/Activity;ILandroid/content/DialogInterface$OnCancelListener;)Z]
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]   Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find any super classes of [com/google/android/gms/common/SupportErrorDialogFragment] (not even immediate super class [android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment]))
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find any super classes of [com/google/android/gms/common/SupportErrorDialogFragment] (not even immediate super class [android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment])
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]  at proguard.evaluation.value.ReferenceValue.generalize(ReferenceValue.java:299)
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]  at proguard.evaluation.value.IdentifiedReferenceValue.generalize(IdentifiedReferenceValue.java:65)
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]  at proguard.evaluation.value.ReferenceValue.generalize(ReferenceValue.java:481)
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]  at proguard.evaluation.Variables.generalize(Variables.java:136)
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]  at proguard.evaluation.TracedVariables.generalize(TracedVariables.java:118)
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]  at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateSingleInstructionBlock(PartialEvaluator.java:682)
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]  at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateInstructionBlock(PartialEvaluator.java:602)
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]  at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateInstructionBlockAndExceptionHandlers(PartialEvaluator.java:560)
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]  at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute0(PartialEvaluator.java:264)
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]  at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute(PartialEvaluator.java:181)
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]  at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.accept(CodeAttribute.java:101)
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]  at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.attributesAccept(ProgramMethod.java:79)
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]  at proguard.classfile.attribute.visitor.AllAttributeVisitor.visitProgramMember(AllAttributeVisitor.java:95)
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]  at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitProgramMethod(SimplifiedVisitor.java:91)
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]  at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.accept(ProgramMethod.java:71)
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]  at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.methodsAccept(ProgramClass.java:504)
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]  at proguard.classfile.visitor.AllMethodVisitor.visitProgramClass(AllMethodVisitor.java:47)
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]  at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:346)
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]  at proguard.classfile.ClassPool.classesAccept(ClassPool.java:116)
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]  at proguard.optimize.Optimizer.execute(Optimizer.java:372)
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]  at proguard.ProGuard.optimize(ProGuard.java:306)
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:115)
[2014-06-20 23:11:38 - Dictionary]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

maybe something wrong with my local configures...
I tried to `-keep` and `-dontwarn` different classes but now nothing helped...

Please help me!

Answer (score 4):

Add android-support-v4.jar to your project

Answer (score 2):

If you use Eclipse ADT : You should be referencing a copy of the library Google Play Services that you copied to your development workspace—you should not reference the library directly from the Android SDK directory.

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing similar problem and few other with Prograud while generating signed build. After lot of search , finally I am able to resolve my problem. I am sure people have better solution than below one.

1. Keep the latest SDK and supported libraries.
2. Create a folder "libs" within "/sdk/tools/progaurd/".
3. Copy .jar files for example "android-support-v13.jar","google-play-services.jar" that are needed by your application in "/sdk/tools/progaurd/libs/" folder.
4. Copy .jar in your application "libs" folder. 
   Also remove "android-support-v4.jar" as it is not required, here v13 already supports v4
5. Add .jar file to your build path.
   Also remove "android-support-v4.jar" from build path as it is not required, here v13 already supports v4.
6. Add below lines in your application project.properties file. Please keep target as "android-22" only.

> ```
> proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
> # Project target.
> target=android-22
> android.library.reference.1=../../dev/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
> ```

7. My Progaurd file "proguard-android.txt". Please change it as per your requirement.

> ```
> -optimizationpasses 2
> -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
> -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
> -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
> -dontpreverify
> -dontshrink
> -verbose
>
> -dontwarn org.apache.**
> -dontwarn org.slf4j.**
> -dontwarn org.json.*
> -dontwarn org.mortbay.**
> -dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
> -dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
> -dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
> -dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.**
> -dontwarn javax.xml.**
> -dontwarn javax.management.**
> -dontwarn java.lang.management.**
>
> -libraryjars libs/android-support-v13.jar
> -libraryjars libs/google-play-services.jar
>
>
> -dontwarn android.support.v13.**    
> -keep class android.support.v13.** { *; }  
> -keep interface android.support.v13.app.** { *; }  
> -keep public class * extends android.support.v13.**   
> -keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
>
> -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
> -keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
>
>
> -dontwarn com.google.code.**
> -dontwarn oauth.signpost.**
> -dontwarn twitter4j.**
> -dontwarn com.google.ads.**
> -dontwarn org.acra.**
>
>
> -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
> -allowaccessmodification
> -keepattributes *Annotation*
> -renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
> -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
> -repackageclasses ''
>
> -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
> -keep public class * extends android.app.Application
> -keep public class * extends android.app.Service
> -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
> -keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
> -keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
> -keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
> -keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
> -keep public class com.google.code.linkedinapi.**
> -keep public class android.content.** { *; }
>
>
>
> -keep class javax.**  { *; }
> -keep class org.**  { *; }
> -keep class twitter4j.**  { *; }
> -keep class java.lang.management.**  { *; }
> -keep class com.google.code.**  { *; }
> -keep class oauth.signpost.**  { *; }
>
>
> -keep class org.acra.** { *; }
>
>
>
> -keepclassmembers public class com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.LinkedInApiXppClient {
>      public <init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.String);
> }
>
>
> -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
>     native <methods>;
> }
>
> -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
>     public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
> }
>
> -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
>     public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
> }
>
>
> -keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
>   public static <fields>;
> }
>
>
> -keepclassmembers enum * {
>     public static **[] values();
>     public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
> }
>
> -keep public class * {
>     public protected *;
> }
>
> -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
>   public static final ** CREATOR;
> }
> ```

Best Regards,
Vik

Answer (score 0):

even though i had google play services as a library i still had to manually add android-support-v4.jar to my libs folder and right click and add to build path in eclipse.

my proguard file looked like this:

```
 -optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontwarn com.google.**
-dontpreverify
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*





-keep class !mycode.** { *; }
```

the last line make it so only my code is obfuscated.  Its more cleaner.